# Select Box Css - a triangle indicating dropdown

Tags: css

Following is a select box:

[image]

Rather then having the traditional drop down icon i am intending to have a different colored yellow triangle shape indicating the dropdown.

```
select {
font-family: inherit;
font-size: inherit;
line-height: inherit;
background-color: #363583;
border-color: #363583;
color: #A2A1C6;
}
```

How to achieve such look.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code for the drop down.

Comment: Please find the applied css

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown styling is a interesting thing. 
If you have a customized dropdown where the current element is a span you could use the ::after selector to make something like this

```
position: absolute;
border-left: 0.7rem solid transparent;
border-bottom: 0.7rem solid #777;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

But Kumar is right, we kinda need the code of your dropdown to know what we can do with it.